# Grunt error: Cannot find module 'time-grunt'

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

I try to install time-grunt local and global, clear npm cache, update npm, but nothing helps.
I get:

```
 Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
 Error: Cannot find module 'time-grunt'
 Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

My version of packages:
node: '0.10.31',
npm: '1.4.23'

After run:
npm install --save-dev time-grunt
in package.json state:

```
"devDependencies": {
"grunt": "^0.4.5",
...
"time-grunt": "^1.0.0"
}
```

This is part of my grunfile.js:

```
module.exports = function( grunt ) {
     require('time-grunt')(grunt);
 
     grunt.initConfig({
     // grunt tasks here
     });
     // load tasks here
     // register task here
}
```

Other grunt tasks running without error.

I'm not understand what is wrong.

How I can test correctly installation of time-grunt by CLI?

Comment: could you show us the Gruntfile.js to make sure your actually requiring the modules etc

Comment: This is part of my grunfile.js:

module.exports = function( grunt ) {

    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({ .. });

    ...

}

Comment: seems as if either the node-modules isnt being looked up properly or grunt-time hasnt installed correctly. with teh information available not much more i can do

Comment: after install grun-time i have in project subfolder node_modules new folder 'time-grunt'. Fanks for your attention on my problem )

Comment: How I can test correctly installation of time-grunt by command line?

Comment: if you just start a node shell in your project directory you should be able to `var t = require('time-grunt');`

Comment: after run "var t = require('time-grunt');" i have "undefined", but after " console.log( require('time-grunt').toString() ) i have source of module.exports function from time-grunt\index.js

Comment: that implies that is is installed correctly, i'm at a loss as to any possible solution, sorry

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add it inside dependencies and not within devDependencies. This way you don't need to separately run `$ npm install --save-dev time-grunt`

```
{
  "name": "grunt-build",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "time-grunt": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compress": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-remove-logging": "~0.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Shiyaz, You're absolutely right! Now **time-grunt** work!

Answer (score 5):

use `npm install` or `sudo npm install` in the folder with package.json

Answer (score 4):

I ended up installing all grunt dependencies manually.

```
npm install time-grunt
npm install load-grunt-config
```

and then all modules listed here:

[image]

Note: you can install all of the dependencies in the photo above in one go with `npm install`.

Finally I ran the `grunt` command and it worked!

Comment: still getting errors regarding can't find the module